# Utilizar propiedades del control base que esta dentro del UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, usercontrol

¿Cómo puedo utilizar las propiedades de los controles que están dentro de un control de usuario sin tener que utilizar `DependencyProperty`?

Ya que, si por ejemplo quiero utilizar todas las propiedades de un botón, tendría que declarar todas estas, no sería como hacer la rueda de nuevo?

Y si existe otra forma sin control de usuario y es la correcta, agradecería que la respondan.

Código del UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.UserControl01"
                 ...
                 >
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="uc_btn" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Código utilizando el UserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControls.wnd02"
        ...
        >
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl01 uc_btn.Background="Red" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un UserControl no tiene porqué ser de tipo "UserControl", qué quiero decir con esto? que en el etiquetado XAML puedes perfectamente cambiar `<UserControl>` por `<Button>` y de ese modo acceder a sus propiedades, como hacer esto?

En vez de tener esto que muestras arriba:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.UserControl01" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="uc_btn" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Puedes tener esto otro:

```
<Button x:Class="UserControls.UserControl01" ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ...
        </Style>
    </Button.Style> 
</UserControl>
```

Y el code-behind lo haces heredar de Button:

```
public partial class UserControl01: Button
```

Ya con eso le dices al compilador que ese UserControl que estás usando debe ser tratado como un botón y por tanto te mostrará sus propiedades nativas.

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda.